# Android RMI with UI Thread

Tags: android

I am trying to remote invoke method form other apk. Everything is working except fact that invoking method has to do some operations on UI and must be run from UI Thread. Method which was invoked with Method.invoke() are running in separate thread and has no access to UI. Is AsyncTask is a proper way to solve this problem? Or maybe exists a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [runOnUIThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) methods specially for situations like this.. you can use them..

you can use handler like this..

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){

public void run(){
//UI operation...

}

});
```

if you are inside an Activity.. then..

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){
//UI operation...

}

});
```